# Iphone: XML image problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, rss, uiimageview, nsxmlparser

I have a question about parsing XML and putting it into a table. I parsed the following elements from a RSS feed : ***title***, ***dc:creator*** and ***enclosure url*** (= an image).

The parsing is working, i can see everything showing up in the console. But when i try to load everything into the tablecell, everything shows up except for the image. So i figured that the problem must be in the CellForRowatIndexPath method in the RootViewController.m ( or in the TableCell.m)

What am i doing wrong? Please help! Ive been struggling for days with this and just cant seem to figure it out!

**Heres the CellForRowatIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 WerkTableCell *cell = (WerkTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WerkCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell =self.werkCell;
                 }
// Configure the cell.
NSMutableArray *cont= [xmlcont items];// is niet in tablevb v. PS

ItemData *current =[cont objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.titelLabel.text = [current titel];
cell.makerLabel.text = [current maker];
cell.thumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[current image]];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`imageNamed:` will only load a local file. In all likelihood, your URL is pointing to a remote file, and you're going to have to fetch it from a web server before you can load it into the table.